# html page url to open specific worksheet in excel 2013 spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, excel-2013

I'm having difficulty getting a link to open a workbook to a specific sheet upon opening.  Using javascript in an html web page (not within an excel workbook), I have a variable of "url" with the following code:

```
url=("http://sharepoint.oursite.com/sites/WF/Team%20files/Rotation%20Schedule/Schedule%20June%20" + year + ".xlsm#'" + weekday + " " + month + "-" + day + "'")}
```

When setting up an alert to display the url prior to opening, it sees it like this:

```
http://sharepoint.oursite.com/sites/WF/Team%20Files/Rotation%20Schedule/Schedule%20June%202016.xlsm#'Sunday 6-05'
```

So it *seems* like the address is correct, and it opens the workbook, but it only goes to the sheet it was on when last saved and not the sheet specific in the address.

I read it was possible to do this, but maybe not?  Or am I doing something wrong.  I've spent a few days searching and haven't come up with anything that works, so posting here as a last resort before giving up.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Edit:
This is one example of a page I came across while searching:
https://superuser.com/questions/205728/how-do-you-specify-a-specific-worksheet-to-open-for-a-ms-excel-workbook-using-a

I tried changing the tab name to just "Sunday" instead of "Sunday 6-05" but it still pulls up the last tab it was saved on, which is "Saturday 6-04".  The code was modified too to remove the " 6-04" characters.

Tried it without the `'` too with no luck.

Comment: What's is that service supposed to do?

Comment: It's supposed to open the "Schedule June 2016.xlsm" workbook, and automatically open the "Sunday 6-05" sheet.  Right now it opens to the last sheet that was active when the workbook was saved, which is labeled "Saturday 6-04".

Comment: Maybe without the `'`s? (`Schedule%20June%202016.xlsm#Sunday 6-05`)

Comment: I saw that like too. I guess it has something to do with the spaces in the sheets name. Try to create a spreadsheet with names without spaces - then try do download it and specify specific sheet. If it will work then it might give you a clue how to continue debugging it

Comment: you can't do that IMO, it's up to the OS how and with wich software it opens a downloaded file